# How do I get UnityEngine.InputSystem to work

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

No matter what I do, I keep getting the VisualStudio error:
"The type or namespace ‘InputSystem’ does not exist in the namespace ‘UnityEngine’.

To summarize what I’ve done:

- Installed the package
- Set ‘Active Input Handling’ to the new system.
- Regenerated project files (with and without Registry packages checked)
- Toyed around in the Packages/Manifest.json

I’ve tried this on three separate versions of unity on two different computers.
I have gotten this to work in the past but nothing I’ve tried has worked this time.

If I manually add a reference to the InputSystem.dll to my project, visual studio stops complaining.
But the error does not go away in Unity and after closing and reopening everything the references are gone from visual studio. I assume that whatever I’ve done Unity is still not tracking those references so they get wiped out the next time project files are recreated.

I'm using VisualStudio 2022 and Unity 2022.3.4f1
I have also tried:
Unity 2021.3.3f1
Unity 2021.3.12f1

Comment: well, it does depend on a lot of things, did you let unity restart when you changed the input system? do you have assembly definition files splitting your code up where you need to add it as usable? no you dont need to add the dll manually, you might need to restart visual studio and unity or make it regen the project files

Comment: It sounds like you are using assembly definitions and didn't add the Input system one as a [reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html#reference-another-assembly)?

Comment: I restarted unity after changing input system, several times (i've removed and reinstalled the thing just to be sure).  I'm not doing anything fancy with assembly deffinitions yet so I should just have the standard Assembly-CSharp.dll.  I've regenerated project files a few times with different settings but to no avail.

To my knowledge I'm not using anything other than the default assembly definition.  But I'll take a look at the manual page and see if there's anything there that might help.

Comment: It was an assembly definition problem, adding the reference fixed everything.  I think it all happened when we spit up our testing code, thanks for the help!